# Web Scraping, Infinite scrolling and extracting links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract all the links like "Saudi Sim Card" from "https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/c/travel-n-tours". I am using Selenium web driver to scroll the web page but i am unable to extract all the links. The error i get says "object of type None has no href attribute" Any suggestions? 
[image]

```
from PageScroller import WebPageScroller
import bs4 as bs

sourceUrl='https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/c/travel-n-tours'

#----------------------- Scrolling to the bottom of page and getting source code --------------------------------------#

scrollObject=WebPageScroller
pageSource=scrollObject.getScrolledPageSource(scrollObject,sourceUrl)

# ------------------------------------- Getting links ---------------------------------- #
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')

blogUrls=[]
for url in soup.find_all('a'):

    if((url.get('href').find('/forums/t/')!=-1) and (url.get('href').find('about-the-travel-n-tours-category')==-1) and (url.get('href').find('/forums/t/topic/')==-1)):
        blogUrls.append(url.get('href'))
        print(url.get('href'))       
print(len(blogUrls))
```

Comment: This site works by posting code, showing results, and asking a specific question.

Comment: I edited the question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: I don't have yet the privilege to upload an image directly. I can only add the image as a link. How can get that privilege?

Answer (score 0):

Scraping with Selenium is generally terrible and the odds are slim-to-none that you'll find a way to deal with the infinite scroll.

This site basically has a JSON endpoint at `https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/c/travel-n-tours/l/latest.json?_=<uts>`, where `<uts>` is a Unix timestamp.

Basically, here's how this works. Open Chrome DevTools or Firebug and load the forum screen. Check out the `Network` tab. There's a `XHR` file called something like `latest.json?_=1491493915518`. Click on it.

The `Request URL` displays as `https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/c/travel-n-tours/l/latest.json?_=1491493915518`. This is your endpoint.

Now all you need is a Unix timestamp and a few lines of code:

```
import requests

current_uts = from_some_unix_timestamp_source  
response = requests.get('https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/c/travel-n-tours/l/latest.json?_={}'.format(current_uts))
print(response.json())
```

And you get back a JSON representation of everything on that page. If you re-run the same script with a more recent timestamp, it will retrieve new forum threads. You could also go back in time with an old Unix timestamp if you wanted to retrieve older threads (or even scrape the entire forum). I'll leave it to you to figure out how to build this out into something more robust.